# AppendBlockAsync with more than 4mb works locally but not on Azure app service

Tags: .net-core, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I am trying to reproduce an issue I see on our production server when using AppendBlobs.

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Understanding-Block-Blobs--Append-Blobs--and-Page-Blobs?redirectedfrom=MSDN#about-append-blobs) state

> Each block in an append blob can be a different size, up to a maximum of 4 MiB, and an append blob can include up to 50,000 blocks. The maximum size of an append blob is therefore slightly more than 195 GiB (4 MiB X 50,000 blocks).

Which rings true with what I'm seeing on our production app, and sure enough I see these exceptions:

> The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit.
> RequestId:3cb3ffd7-001e-0087-5789-ae3e0c000000
> Time:2023-07-04T15:10:01.2687679Z
> Status: 413 (The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit.)
> ErrorCode: RequestBodyTooLarge

The problem I am having is I cannot reproduce this issue in a test.

I've got a minimal reproducible example below, which essentially creates a memory stream to a specified size, by serializing a bunch of GUIDs to a string.

I then use `AppendBlob` to append the blob...

I can see the `memoryStream.Length` is indeed greater than 4mb.

However, the puzzling thing is, this works. The file is uploaded to Blob Storage correctly, without exception.

I have seen ways to 'fix' the exception (chunking the memory stream, for example) but I was trying to reproduce this in a test first, but I can't seem to reproduce the error anywhere.

Any ideas what is happening?

```
[Fact]
public async Task Can_append_blob_even_if_larger_than_4mb()
{
    var containerClient  = new BlobServiceClient(ConnectionString)
        .GetBlobContainerClient("test-123");
    
    await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

    var outputFilename = $"Test-{DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}.txt";
    var appendBlobClient = containerClient.GetAppendBlobClient(outputFilename);
    await appendBlobClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

    var json = JsonConvert
        .SerializeObject(CreateList(6));

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));

    await appendBlobClient
        .AppendBlockAsync(memoryStream);
}

private static List<object> CreateList(int sizeInMb)
{
    const int mbInBytes = 1024 * 1024;

    var maxSizeInBytes = sizeInMb * mbInBytes;

    var totalSize = 0;

    var list = new List<object>();

    while (totalSize < maxSizeInBytes)
    {
        var obj = Guid.NewGuid();
        var serializedObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        
        var objectSize = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedObj).Length;

        if (objectSize + totalSize > maxSizeInBytes)
        {
            break;
        }

        list.Add(obj);
        totalSize += objectSize;
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Are you connecting to an actual storage account when running the code locally or just connected to storage emulator (Azurite)?

Comment: Actual storage account in Azure. Emulator doesn't support AppendBlobs

Comment: Hmmm...it should not be happening. Can you try by creating a simple console application with the same code and executing it instead of running your code in a test?

Comment: yeah, same with console app, too

Comment: you are handing over **6**  as parameter  => `CreateList`  ... using **4** should work  =>  so you need to take a closer look into your `maxSizeInBytes` variable ... it is wrongly used

Comment: @DimiTakis the parameter 6 that you're referring to just specifies the size of the memory stream (in mb) to create - anything over 4 _should_ cause the failure - but it's not

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the source of `int AppendBlobClient.AppendBlobMaxAppendBlockBytes`

This is

```cs
public virtual int AppendBlobMaxAppendBlockBytes => 
    ClientConfiguration.Version < BlobClientOptions.ServiceVersion.V2022_11_02
        ? Constants.Blob.Append.Pre_2022_11_02_MaxAppendBlockBytes
        : Constants.Blob.Append.MaxAppendBlockBytes;
```

Where these constants are:

```cs
 public const int Pre_2022_11_02_MaxAppendBlockBytes = 4 * Constants.MB; // 4MB
 public const int MaxAppendBlockBytes = 100 * Constants.MB; // 100MB
```

This larger size is not (yet) documented.
This is defined in the package `Azure.Storage.Blobs Version 12.17.0`, released 2023-07-11.

**However**, in the previous package version, `12.16.0` we see something different:

```cs
public virtual int AppendBlobMaxAppendBlockBytes => Constants.Blob.Append.MaxAppendBlockBytes;
        
const int MaxAppendBlockBytes = 4 * Constants.MB; // 4MB
```

Hypothesis:

The test code and container is using the new, larger 100Mb value.
The failing code is using the smaller 4Mb value.

it looks like this check is carried out by *Azure* and not by the Azure client code, so updating the Azure client package does not in itself fix the issue; in fact can make it worse if it tells you that can write 100Mb, when you can not, or vice versa.

This could explain why a recently-created container works where an older one does not.  Is this size limit in Azure a container or an account setting? Can it be changed non-destructively on existing containers? Unfortunately this is not yet documented.

You can control this setting with options, e.g.

```cs
var opts = new BlobClientOptions(BlobClientOptions.ServiceVersion.V2021_12_02);
var client = new AppendBlobClient(uri, creds, opts);
```

But while this sets `int AppendBlobClient.AppendBlobMaxAppendBlockBytes`, it does not in itself cause "chunking", you still [have to append chunks of the max size like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-append#create-an-append-blob-and-append-data).

The docs still mostly just talk about 4Mb, but see [here in "Versioning for Azure Storage"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services):

> The max append block content length has been raised from 4 MiB to 100 MiB.